# How to add new variable for flash message with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

In my RoR app, I'm passing flash messages using "notice" and "alert".
But, when I'm trying to pass like flash["warning"], for example, I receive: `undefined local variable or method warning'`

What can I do to be able to create a flash message passing 'warning' value?

Code:

```
#app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def create
    user = params["user"]

    if User.find_by_email(user["email"]).nil?
      set_flash_message(:testing, :email_not_found) if is_navigational_format?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(user)

      if successfully_sent?(resource)
        respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
      else
        respond_with(resource)
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    root_path
  end
end

#app/views/landing/index.html.erb
.
.
<h5><%= testing %></h5>
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a symbol. `flash[:warning] = "XYZ"` for example.

Comment: Are you really using Rails 3 or are you using Rails 4?

Comment: Then you should output the flash like this: `<h5><%= flash[:testing] %></h5>`